# aiogram: Executing telegram bot's commands by his mention

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

is there any way to create bot commands that are callable from external chat? something like @gamebot

[image: gamebot Example]

This is how I create a normal command, but it doesn't work in external chats.

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=['hello'])
async def hello_callback(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Hello World!')
```

Answer (score 0):

What the first picture shows is called "inline" functionality. Please see [the Telegram docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/inline) for more info. The aiogram docs also provide an [example for an inline bot](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/inline_bot.html).